# Parsing .csv file into an array (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, parsing

So i got this .csv file with values written like this :

mots;occurrences
franc;424
france;368
année;234
euro;233
pays;165
nation;164
part;153
europe;150
sent;146
faire;137
français;134
travail;133
port;128
monde;124
fort;124
compatriotes;120
...

(mots & occurrences are the columns and the values to each are below them)

i need to convert / parse this file in my react component in order to make an array (named words) that looks like this :

const words = [
{
text: 'told',
value: 64,
},
{
text: 'mistake',
value: 11,
},
{
text: 'thought',
value: 16,
},
{
text: 'bad',
value: 17,
},
]

can someone help me on doing this in React.js ?

I tried this but it keeps on showing me errors:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { csv } from "d3-fetch";
import ReactWordcloud from "react-wordcloud";
import { csvParse } from "d3-dsv";
function WordCloud({ id }) {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    let fileName = "";

    if (id === "0") {
        fileName = "./data/1974-2022.csv";
    }
    else {
        fileName = "./data/1974-2022.csv";
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        csv(fileName)
            .then(text => {
                const words = data.map(d => ({ text: d.mots.toString(), value: parseInt(d.occurrences) })).slice(0, 30);
                console.log(words)
                setData(words);
                setLoading(false);
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }, [fileName]);

    if (loading) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <ReactWordcloud words={data}/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default WordCloud;
```

My arrays are always empty when i try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generated myself some mock data to test your code with and found some bugs:

- You did not import the csv file in your WordCloud component which part of the reason why the array is empty. Import it like this:

```
    import MOCK_DATA from "./data/MOCK_DATA.csv";
```

- Your `data object` is initialized with an empty array so when you try to `.map` it, it will map over 0 elements so it effectively skips this block of code:

```
    const words = data
        .map((d) => ({
            text: d.mots.toString(),
            value: parseInt(d.occurrences)
        }))
        .slice(0, 30);
```

Here is the complete code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { csv } from "d3-fetch";
import ReactWordcloud from "react-wordcloud";
import { csvParse } from "d3-dsv";
import MOCK_DATA from "./data/MOCK_DATA.csv";

function WordCloud({ id }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  let fileName = "";

  if (id === "0") {
    fileName = MOCK_DATA;
  } else {
    fileName = MOCK_DATA;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);

    csv(fileName)
      .then((text) => {
        const words = text
          .map((d) => ({
            text: d.word.toString(),
            value: parseInt(d.occurrence)
          }))
          .slice(0, 30);

        setData(words);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, [fileName]);

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactWordcloud words={data} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default WordCloud;
```

Hope this helps :) Check it out on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-frost-ojmdgk)

Comment: It works really well with your sandbox and my own data but when i implements it to my own code i got this error and it just showing me a blank page : TypeError: d.mots is undefined
    words Wordcloud.jsx:25
    WordCloud Wordcloud.jsx:23

Comment: update: my wordcloud is there but the words are just not showing mb

Comment: I suggest just putting console.log() everywhere the data changes to check out what is happening because without more context of your code I can't help out much.

Also, is the 'words' array being populated accordingly?